# ffmpeg on Raspberry Pi unable to stitch many photos into video

Tags: camera, ffmpeg

I'm working on a program in which I have a folder full of images, named in the form `image0000.jpg`, `image00001.jpg`, and so on, and I want to stitch these images together into a video.

To do this, in my Python script, I have the following line:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-framerate', str(framerate), '-i', 'path/to/input/image%04d.jpg', 'path/to/output/video.mp4])
```

This executes `ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i path/to/input/image%04d.jpg path/to/output/video.mp4` in the terminal.

My script works when the number of pictures is relatively low (6-10), but when it gets higher (~60), ffmpeg just produces an empty video.

Why is this? What can I do to get it to work for larger amounts of input pictures? Is there an alternate way to stitch photos together into a video timelapse that my Raspberry Pi can handle?

Comment: This is a general Python question - not Pi specific. Try unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's also a general ffmpeg question.  I'd run the command without using Python and check the reported error (if any).